# Branch moved folder based on label or date 

Tags: tfs, branch, label

I've moved a folder in tfs using the "move" command but now I cannot create branches off the moved folder based on date or label (label was created when source was in the old folder).  I can however create a branch based on "latest version".  I get an error message "no items match  in  if I try to branch of a label.  I'm guessing the label references files using the old folder before I moved it.  I also get no files if I try to "get specific version" by either date or label.

I've tried to roll back moving the folder but this gives me errors such as "An unexpected error occured".

Answer (score 1):

If you need to branch from points in time prior to the move, you need to specify the old name.

```
# fails
tf branch $/project/folder-newname $/project/folder-somebranch /version:Loldlabel

# should work
tf branch $/project/folder-oldname $/project/folder-somebranch /version:Loldlabel
```

Comment: Does not appear to be possible from the UI (in VS2012 at least), but  tf.exe from the command line as in this example works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error related to rollback was that I had to roll back a folder rename first.  I could then roll back moving the folder.